# Matlab yyplot label and plot

Tags: matlab

I want to plot e_eff5(2) the imaginary and real part as undotted, normal line and the e_eff5(1) the imaginary and real part as dotted.
The real parts are on the left size(blue), the imaginary on the right side(red). Then i want tolabel the 4 lines, dotted blue, normal blue, dotted red, normal red.

```
i=1;
for T = 20:5:25

teta = 1 - 300/(273.15 + T);
e0 = 77.66 - 103.3 * teta;
e_unendlich = 0.066 * e0;
yd = 20.27 + 146.5 * teta + 314 * teta^2; %relaxation frequency

e_eff5(i,:) = (e0 - e_unendlich)./(1 - j.* f ./ (yd * 10^9)) + e_unendlich;

i=i+1;
end

figure(5);
plotyy(fGhz,e_eff5(1,:), fGhz,imag(e_eff5(1,:)));
legend(strcat('real T ={ }', 20, '°C'), strcat('imag T ={ } ', 25, '°C'));
hold on;
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(fGhz,e_eff5(2,:), fGhz,imag(e_eff5(2,:)));
set(hLine1,'LineStyle','--')
set(hLine2,'LineStyle','--')
%title('Water Single Debye Model below 100 GHz as a function of temperature Manabe Fit');
title('Wasser Permittivität einzelnes Debye Model (gültig unter 100 GHz)');
xlabel('Frequenz [GHz]');
%ylabel('rel. Permittivität \epsilonr [ ]');

ylabel(hAx(1),'rel. Permittivität Realteil \epsilonr [ ]') % left y-axis 
ylabel(hAx(2),'rel. Permittivität Imaginarteil \epsilonr [ ]') % right y-axis
legend(strcat('real T ={ }', 20, '°C'), strcat('imag T ={ } ', 25, '°C'));


grid on
grid minor
```

Comment: I suggest you read up on the plot documentation in Matlab and particularly on the `LineSpec` property of `plot`: `doc plot`. The examples of the plotyy documentation also seem helpful

Comment: I did it from the documentation, set line should work, but doesnt seem to work